# Issue with batch class soql query returning values

Tags: apex, soql, batch

I am a newbie to salesforce development of batch classes

```
query = 'SELECT Id,Auto_close_Date__c, Status, RecordType.DeveloperName, ' + 
                               Disable_Auto_Close__c, ' +
                        'FROM Case ' +
                        'WHERE (((Status = \'SS\' OR Status = \'WF\' AND RecordTypeAPI__c NOT IN:RecordTypeName)' + 
                        'OR (Status = \'FP\' AND (RecordTypeAPI__c = \'A\' OR RecordTypeAPI__c = \'B\'))) ' +
                        
                        'AND Disable_Auto_Close__c = False ' +
                        'AND Account.Name != \'QA\' ' +
                        'AND Auto_close_Date__c <=today';
```

above query is throwing error, basically I am trying to achieve if the status is "SS" or "WF" it should pull the all case recordtypes which are not in RecordTypeNam or if status is "FP" it should only pull for recordtype A or B. which is not happening. it is giving error as expecting a parenthesis. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're missing a `'` in your code (if this is a copy-paste error, feel free to ignore this advice). Syntax highlighting could have helped you here:

[image: Syntax Highlighting Missing Quote]

Second, you did have an extra parentheses:

```
'WHERE ((Status = \'SS\' OR Status = \'WF\' AND RecordTypeAPI__c NOT IN:RecordTypeName)'+
   //  ^--There were three here
```

Third, you don't need the string, which makes it easier to read, *and*, as a bonus, you get syntax highlighting.

```
Database.getQueryLocator([
    SELECT Id,Auto_close_Date__c, Status, RecordType.DeveloperName, Disable_Auto_Close__c
    FROM Case
    WHERE ((Status = 'SS' OR Status = 'WF' AND RecordTypeAPI__c NOT IN:RecordTypeName) 
            OR (Status = 'FP' AND (RecordTypeAPI__c = 'A' OR RecordTypeAPI__c = 'B')))
            AND Disable_Auto_Close__c = False
            AND Account.Name != 'QA'
            AND Auto_close_Date__c <=today
]);
```

[image: Extra parentheses in code]

This is actually how I found the extra parentheses.

Notice how the `]` is red? This means you missed a parentheses somewhere. They're also colored such that blue, orange, purple, etc are paired together for easy visualization.

Fourth, you can optimize your query using IN:

```
Database.getQueryLocator([
    SELECT Id,Auto_close_Date__c, Status, RecordType.DeveloperName, Disable_Auto_Close__c
    FROM Case
    WHERE ((Status IN ('SS','WF') AND RecordTypeAPI__c NOT IN:RecordTypeName) 
            OR (Status = 'FP' AND RecordTypeAPI__c IN ('A','B')))
            AND Disable_Auto_Close__c = False
            AND Account.Name != 'QA'
            AND Auto_close_Date__c <=today
]);
```

Fifth, if possible, I suggest you fix the `NOT IN :RecordTypeName` filter, as this causes the query engine to not use indexes. Just list all the record types that *should* be included.

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you please let me know which tool did you use to find the syntax error?

Comment: @sfdcuser I'm using [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with [Bracket Pair Colorizer 2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2) for enhanced bracket highlighting, and of course, the [Salesforce Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode) and [Salesforce CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) for deployments.

Comment: @sfdcuser All of this is free software, too, which is my ideal price tag.

Comment: could you also help me to understand how to use that tool in vs code 2, I have installed the extension and couldnt find any article or blog which help me. Thanks again.

Comment: @sfdcuser When you create a new file (Ctrl-N), press Ctrl-K M, select Apex from the list, and you can start using it. The brackets plugin works automatically on any file type.

Comment: query = 'SELECT Id,Auto_close_Date__c, Status, RecordType.DeveloperName, ' + 
                              'Disable_Auto_Close__c, ' +
                        'FROM Case ' +
                        'WHERE ((Status = \'SS\' OR Status = \'WF\' AND RecordTypeAPI__c NOT IN:RecordTypeName)' + 
                        'OR (Status = \'FP\' AND (RecordTypeAPI__c = \'A\' OR RecordTypeAPI__c = \'B\'))) ' +
                        'AND Disable_Auto_Close__c = False ' +
                        'AND Account.Name != \'QA\' ' +
                        'AND Auto_close_Date__c <=today';

Comment: I am above using query didnt find any syntax errors but when I run the batch job it gives me error First error: expecting a right parentheses, found 'AND'

Comment: @sfdcuser Again, I'd recommend not using a String here. There's no need for it. That said, your error comes from combining `AND` and `OR` without parentheses. You can't do this. Again, I recommend using `IN` instead of `OR` here. The relevant line to fix is: `'WHERE ((Status = \'SS\' OR Status = \'WF\' AND RecordTypeAPI__c NOT IN:RecordTypeName)' +` which should be: `'WHERE (((Status = \'SS\' OR Status = \'WF\') AND RecordTypeAPI__c NOT IN:RecordTypeName)' +` (or, again, strongly recommend the use of IN).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to resolve it by not using string.